# Unable to Connect to AWS Glue Schema Registry

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I am trying to connect to AWS Glue Schema registry and would like to use WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.
As part of it, I tried the following in my custom serializer class ( extends GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaSerializer )

```
 WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.create();
```

This would return me an error saying

```
 software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException:Multiple HTTP Implementation found in class path
```

To avoid this, I tried using StsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider where I can get hang of choosing a HTTP client

```
SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder().build();
StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder().region(Region.<region_name>).httpClient(httpClient).build();
StsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider stsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider = StsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider
        .builder()
        .stsClient(stsClient)
        .build();
```

With this approach, I am stuck with the following error:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).
```

The issue is that I cannot provide hardcoded values to system properties/environment variables as I work in an enterprise.

More details:

I see from AWS logs that TLS handshake is successful and secure connection is established.
Then it tries to do the following "Loading credentials from WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider" and I get the above exception.

Can someone help me how I can connect to the Glue Schema registry with fetching credentials from WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider ?

**Edit:
Code snippet on how I am trying to fetch:**

A custom class ( CustomSerializer) extends GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaSerializer and the constructor of the extended class looks something like this:

```
 public CustomSerializer()
{ 
super( stsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider(),null,null); 
}

    public static StsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider stsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider(){

   
        SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder().build();
        StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder().region(Region.<region_name>).httpClient(httpClient).build();


        StsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider stsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider = StsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider
                .builder()
                .stsClient(stsClient)
                .build();
        return  stsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider;


    }
```

Comment: can you share a snippet of your custom class

Comment: also are you not allowed to use any kind of system properties? or just can't use any of them for setting AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID?

Comment: No, I cannot use the system properties.
I have made an edit to the query where you could find the code snippet.

Comment: why can't you use system.properties?